# How do I import a python library from a different folder?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using the adafruit python library for raspberry pi.

This is the file location I want to import to my file

```
/projectfolder/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_7Segment.py
```

And this is where the file is that i'm trying to import the library to

```
/projectfolder/start.py
```

I have this in start.py but it isn't working. Any idea why?

```
from Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_7Segment import SevenSegment
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
File "timer.py", line 5
    from Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_7Segment import SevenSegment
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python import statement doesn't allow '-' in the variable name. However, you can still add that path to sys.path and make it working.

Check your sys.path first

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

If this does not include /projectfolder/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack then add it to sys.path

```
>>> sys.path.append('/projectfolder/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack')
>>> from Adafruit_7Segment import SevenSegment
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to run sys.path.append

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'/projectfolder/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack''

Comment: It is not a bash command. Add that line in python program BEFORE import statement.

Answer (score 0):

You put wrong path in the `import` statement, replace the dot with slash:

```
from Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_7Segment import SevenSegment
```